# print if next line contains

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a text file from which 0 hits found protein is needed. I am using Linux suse. Any command using awk or sed will be appreciated

```
# BLASTP 2.2.31+
# Query: ABO10498.2 DNA replication initiator protein [Acinetobacter baumannii ATCC 17978]
# Database: uniprot-reviewed%3Ayes+AND+proteome%3Aup000005640.fasta
# Fields: query id, subject id, evalue, % identity, % query coverage per subject
# 1 hits found
# BLASTP 2.2.31+
# Query: ABO10538.2 hypothetical protein A1S_0043 [Acinetobacter baumannii ATCC 17978]
# Database: uniprot-reviewed%3Ayes+AND+proteome%3Aup000005640.fasta
# 0 hits found
# Query: ABO10591.2 putative acetyl-coA synthetase/AMP-(fatty) acid ligase [Acinetobacter baumannii ATCC 17978]
# Database: uniprot-reviewed%3Ayes+AND+proteome%3Aup000005640.fasta
# Fields: query id, subject id, evalue, % identity, % query coverage per subject
# 23 hits found
# BLASTP 2.2.31+
# Query: ABO10598.2 eR transcriptional regulator [Acinetobacter baumannii ATCC 17978]
# Database: uniprot-reviewed%3Ayes+AND+proteome%3Aup000005640.fasta
# 0 hits found
```

desired output:

```
# BLASTP 2.2.31+
# Query: ABO10538.2 hypothetical protein A1S_0043 [Acinetobacter baumannii ATCC 17978]
# Database: uniprot-reviewed%3Ayes+AND+proteome%3Aup000005640.fasta
# 0 hits found
# BLASTP 2.2.31+
# Query: ABO10598.2 eR transcriptional regulator [Acinetobacter baumannii ATCC 17978]
# Database: uniprot-reviewed%3Ayes+AND+proteome%3Aup000005640.fasta
# 0 hits found
```

Answer (score 7):

If the pattern stays the same, you can use

```
grep -B 3 '# 0 hits found'
```

This will print all lines containing `# 0 hits found` and the three lines before the match.

The different hits are sperated by a line contining `--`. So you might want to add `| grep -v '^--'` to the command.

Comment: Yup, that would be the quickest solution :)